# Am I using the Columns() property improperly, and if so, is there a good workaround?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently in the process of solving a

> type mismatch error

in a macro I'm writing, and I've written a short subroutine to drill down on the specific issue. This subroutine should loop through all of Column A, entering the numbers 1-10 in rows 1-10.

```
Sub looptest()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
    i = 0

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If i < 10 Then
            i = i + 1
            rCell.Value2 = i

        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Instead this fills every cell in Column A with 1. Stepping through it in debug mode shows that instead of referencing a single cell, rCell references the entire column.

I have found that if I replace

`Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(1)`

with

`Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A100")`

the macro works as intended, however I'd prefer to be able to use Columns() or something similar in my production code.

**Am I using the Columns() property improperly, and if so, is there a good workaround?**

Comment: I just tried your code as-is and received no error. The way you have it written, the loop happens only once.

Comment: You are using it correctly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why are you looping 1.04m times to load only the first 10?

Comment: @ScottCraner because this is a quick test sub where I'm not worried about performance. The production code looks more like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Column(1)

Comment: `For Each rCell In rRange.Cells`

Comment: @Banana this is a red herring. I only needed to increment to 10, and am more concerned with the rCell variable containing a full column rather than a single cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner much appreciated, this works perfectly as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin with these changes:

```
 Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Cells

 Dim i As Long
```

Using the `.Cells` lets us loop over the cells in a column rather than columns in a worksheet.

Comment: Perfect fix, adding the .Cells property did the trick. Much appreciated!